# Is the msg.sender address changed while passing to another contract as a parameter?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm here to ask my problem on solidity code.

Here is simple example code. Contract 'Map' has a mapped data. It has each address's T/F values. I created an account `X` and add it to `'simpleMap'`.

Contract 'Ask' lookup mapping data through 'Map' contract. What I expected result when `X` called `askMe()` was `TRUE` but it was always `FALSE`.

When I called `whoIsMsgSender` it returns the exact `X`'s account. What's the problem??

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Map {
    mapping (address => bool) simpleMap;

    function add(address _address) external {
        simpleMap[_address] = true;
    }

    function isTrue(address _address) external view returns (bool _ret) {
        return simpleMap[_address];
    }
}

contract Ask {
    Map public map = Map(Map's address like 0x~~ just for test);
    function askMe() external view returns (bool _ret) {
        return map.isTrue(msg.sender);
    }

    function whoIsMsgSender() external view returns (address _address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your contracts in Remix, but askMe() returned true for me. How are you separating the two contracts? Maybe Map is not yet deployed before Ask is trying to call a function on it. I separated the two contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Map {
    mapping (address => bool) simpleMap;

    function add(address _address) external {
        simpleMap[_address] = true;
    }

    function isTrue(address _address) external view returns (bool _ret) {
        return simpleMap[_address];
    }
}


pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Map { function isTrue(address _address) external view returns (bool _ret); }

contract Ask {
    Map public map = Map(MAP_ADDRESS);
    function askMe() external view returns (bool _ret) {
        return map.isTrue(msg.sender);
    }

    function whoIsMsgSender() external view returns (address _address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was working on customized Ethermint. When the Byzantium is disabled, it happened. I don't know why but it has been solved. Thanks for your kind help!